# Allow favorited contacts to ring the phone when calling in silent mode

Tags: calls, ringtone, silent-mode

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S9 on Android 9. I can allow favorite contacts to call in the "Do not disturb" mode. But I also want them to ring the phone when calling in silent mode.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

In my Motorola G8 Power I can go to Sound configuration, and inside it I have the do not disturb section. There I can select which people, apps or alarms should be able to interrupt the DND mode.

[This Google support post](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335?hl=en) can provide you further information. There you can see, for instance, a section *Set what to block*, transcribed below:

> 1. Open your phone's Settings app.
> 2. Tap Sound & vibration And then Do Not Disturb. .
> 3. Under "What can interrupt Do Not Disturb,"
> 4. choose what to block or allow.
>
>    - People: Block or allow calls, messages, or conversations.
>    - Apps: Choose which apps can send you notifications.
>    - Alarms & other interruptions: Block or allow alarms, media, touch sounds, reminders, or calendar events.
>
> Tip: With any settings, critical notifications show. For example, you can't block system security notifications.

However, if you just lowered the volume, I don't think there is an exception list. [You can find more details about volume and vibration settings at this page](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9082609)

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have a way to ring on silent mode, but here's a workaround I'm stealing from Vicki Hermann on Quora, brilliant.
Set your default ringtone for all contacts as "Silent" (if your phone doesn't natively have a silent ringtone, you can download one).
Then choose the contacts that you like and assign them a custom ringtone. After that you can leave your phone on normal ring mode (stay off silent mode) and no calls will ring except the ones with loud ringtones assigned.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-set-up-my-Android-phone-so-the-phone-only-rings-when-a-specific-person-texts-me-but-is-silent-the-rest-of-the-time/answer/Vicki-Herrmann